# Django security

Tags: django, tastypie

hope someone can help me.

I have a stack with Django and tasty pie (I use apikey to authenticate and authorize the users). Let me explain what Im trying to do.

I have several users who can only access their data, so imagine that a user through  a rest service access all the rows of the model requestoffer, as follows.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/requestoffer/?format=json&username=door1&api_key=84051c6fd1581ad60ffa96bcf5a50d3fc11ccdd3
```

But I dont want that user access all the requestoffers, I just want him to access the ones he is "proprietary".

Do you have any idea how to do this with either Django or Tastypie?

Did I make myself clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every row belongs to one specific user then you can add it as a foreign key to requestoffer and filter the queryset by the user. Another approach would be to extend Authorization class and implement apply_limits.

```
class MyAuthorization(DjangoAuthorization):
    def apply_limits(self, request, object_list):
        if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
            return object_list.filter(requestoffer__user=request.user.id)

        return object_list.none()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achieve permission management. Which one suits your needs is totally up to you. One way to achieve this might be to create an 'ownership' relation with the model in question, then create a manager for that model only returning records based on the request. The documentation on model managers is pretty straight forward (and elegant).

To automate the record ownership you could create a CurrentUserField as described in [Pro Django](http://prodjango.com/), there's also multiple ways to implement that. So a long story short, you should just learn by trial-and-error.